# Generate alphabetic series PHP

Tags: php, series

I want to create alphabetic series in php. The series I want to create is something like:

```
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
ZZZY
ZZZZ
```

I do not want any numbers. Pure alphabetic series. What approach can I use to create this? Any hints or pseudo code would be helpful.

I have already gone through `range function` and using `ascii` values to print alphabets but still could not find a good approach to create such a series.

Comment: Four nested loops iterating over the set of all valid characters. Then all you have to do is concatenate the current character of each loop to a string. That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `while`. PHP can increment characters!!

```
$letter = 'AAAA';
while (($letters[] = $letter++) !== 'ZZZZ') {}
print_r($letters);
```

Comment: This includes sequences with a length of less than 4 characters.

Comment: @RipHunter Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this coding:

```
<?php
for ($char = 'AAAA'; $char <= 'Z'; $char++) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: nice solution ... you nailed it :)

Comment: Thanks. Hope this is useful to you all.

Comment: This is a great solution. But the series only goes till `yzzz`. That is because of `$char <= 'Z';`. Is it possible to make it go all the way to `zzzz`?

Comment: it is printing till `YZZZ` only

Answer (score 1):

Four nested loops iterating over the set of all valid characters. Then all you have to do is concatenate the current character of each loop to a string:

```
<?php
$chars = range('A', 'Z');
$words = [];
foreach ($chars as $char1) {
  foreach ($chars as $char2) {
    foreach ($chars as $char3) {
      foreach ($chars as $char4) {
        $words[] = $char1 . $char2 . $char3 . $char4;
      }
    }
  }
}
var_dump($words);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(456976) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "AAAA"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "AAAB"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "AAAC"
  [3] =>
  string(4) "AAAD"
  [4] =>
  string(4) "AAAE"
  [5] =>
  [...]
```